# How to generate stackexchange pictures with profile information?

Tags: support, profile-page

Time ago I saw a profile with an image like this one:

[image]

So I copied the image url but adapting it to my own user id and I put it in my [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/230230/alter-lagos) page. It has been a while and my reputation is still the same in the image, so I've realized that the url now is `https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QkYT.png` (I remember before was something like `http://www.stackexchange.com/users/[my_user_id].png`)
I've been looking in the help section,another profiles, but no clue. Is still working this functionality? if so, what's the url to generate it? Is specified in some help site? FAQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895789/alter-lagos).

Click the [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895789/alter-lagos/flair) tab:

[image: flair tab]

Enjoy.

Comment: ...it was so close. Thanks :)